# how to show data in view from Viewbag mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razorengine

this is my controller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
       var data = (from o in db.aspnet_Users
                          from q in db.aspnet_Profile
                          where
                          o.UserId == q .UserId
                          select new{
                              o.UserId,
                              o.UserName,
                              q.Address,
                              q.Email,
                              q.Phone,
                              q.Mobile,
                              q.SocialID,                                  
                          }
                          ).ToList();
       ViewData["Allprofile"] = data;
        return View();
    }
```

and i want to show the data in the view in table, there was a problem to show 2 db Models in one view because the model generated from Database not Code First so i'm trying show the data using ViewData any help ?

Comment: Create a view model and pass it rather than using viewbag or viewdata

Answer (score 2):

why are you not using a ViewModel here? you are somewhat defeating the purpose of MVC.
the view model will encapsulate the data you need to show on the View. you pass the view model to the View - the view will accept the strongly typed view.

the ViewData should never really be used for heavy/complex objects for a number of reasons - performance for one, but also no type safety/strongly typed support either.

change your code so you return a ViewModel with the data you need to show to the user.